# que más funciones hay de $.ajax

Tags: ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"",
            data: "",

            error: function (error) {//Función de error
        console.log(error);
        },
        }).done(function(info){//done
            let chat_amigo = document.getElementById("chat_form").elements.user_name_f.value;
            var altura  = $("#chat_conversacion_"+chat_amigo).prop("scrollHeight");
            $("#chat_conversacion_"+chat_amigo).scrollTop(altura);
        },
success: function (response) {//COMPLETE
            $("#mensajespuestos").html(response);
        }
```

);

quisiera saber si hay una de load(carga) osea mientras se va haciendo la petición que se me muestre algo

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr? Si lo que quieres es crear una barra de progreso de una petición AJAX, creo que en el pasado se hizo una pregunta similar (al menos recuerdo responder a una pregunta similar). Si es eso, busca en el sitio y dime si no la encuentras para que te ponga un enlace.

Comment: solo quiero saber tmb , cuantas funciones hay

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es mostrar una imagen, o algo para representar que estas cargando información puedes utilizar `beforeSend` y `complete`

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        //Muestras una imagen antes de enviar
        $('#image').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
        //La ocultas al finalizar
        $('#image').hide();
    },
    success: function(html){
       //Resultado
       $('.info').append(html);
    }
});
```

Saludos, espero que te sea útil!